# discord-modals TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'EPHEMERAL')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using the package `discord-modals` to create better modals with my discord bot.

When I want to reply to the `SlashCommandInteraction` (actually it's the `modalResponse` listening event), then I can't make the reply ephemeral. When I remove the `ephemeral` bool, it works perfectly. But I don't understand why it doesn't work with a normal reply action.

```
await event.reply({content: `${replymsg}`, ephemeral: true});
```

So if I use this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'EPHEMERAL')
    at ModalSubmitInteraction.reply (C:\Users\david_h7tqe3i\WebstormProjects\musicbottest\node_modules\discord-modals\src\v14\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:51:57)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\david_h7tqe3i\WebstormProjects\musicbottest\src\index.js:107:9)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:384:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:85:21)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And if I use the following code, it works:

```
await event.reply({content: `${replymsg}`});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in `discord-modals`. It uses `MessageFlags.FLAGS.EPHEMERAL`, but `MessageFlags.FLAGS` is `undefined`. For a quick fix, you can edit `node_modules/discord-modals/src/v14/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js` and on line 51 replace

```js
data.flags = options.ephemeral ? MessageFlags.FLAGS.EPHEMERAL : undefined;
```

with

```js
data.flags = options.ephemeral ? MessageFlags.Ephemeral : undefined;
```

I've also [opened a PR](https://github.com/Mateo-tem/discord-modals/pull/111), hopefully, the maintainer will accept it soon.